# Receiving JSON data on Web API Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api which is receiving some POST data.
I am able to parse the JSON string when the elements are not nested - but the nested ones just will not parse at all...

Here is the JSON I am receiving:

```
{
    "wlauth": {
        "userid": "user",
        "password": "pass"
    },
    "ident": "01234567890",
    "identtype": "imsi",
    "message": "VGVzdCBNZXNzYWdl"
}
```

Here is the code from the Controller that handles the Post request:

```
public IHttpActionResult ReceiveSMSData(SMSReturned data)
{
 Debug.WriteLine(data.userid);
 Debug.WriteLine(data.password);
 Debug.WriteLine(data.Ident);
 Debug.WriteLine(data.identtype);
 Debug.WriteLine(data.message);
 return Ok();
}
```

From this I get the following in the debug console (the first two lines are blank):

```
'


01234567890
imsi
VGVzdCBNZXNzYWdl'
```

So in other words, the non-nested elements appear fine, but the nested ones do not - what should I be doing differently to retrieve those nested elements?

Edit:

Here is the SMSReturned Class:

```
public class SMSReturned
{
    public string wlauth { get; set; }
    public string Ident { get; set; }
    public string identtype { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: We need to see your models.  Also note that the `visual studio` tag is for questions *about VS*, not coding questions.

Comment: Post the code for the `SMSReturned` class.

Comment: yup we need to see the class

Comment: Here is the code for the SMSReturned class:
`public class SMSReturned
    {
        public string wlauth { get; set; }
        public string Ident { get; set; }
        public string identtype { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string userid { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }'

Comment: wlauth is an object in the json not a string you need to create another model which represents wlauth and make that a property of your SMSReturned class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure for `SMSReturned` is missing some elements. Try this:

```
public class WLAuth
{
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
} 
public class SMSReturned
{

    public WLAuth wlauth { get; set; }
    public string Ident { get; set; }
    public string identtype { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }

}
```

and this:

```
 public IHttpActionResult ReceiveSMSData(SMSReturned data)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine(data.wlauth.userid);
    Debug.WriteLine(data.wlauth.password);
    Debug.WriteLine(data.Ident);
    Debug.WriteLine(data.identtype);
    Debug.WriteLine(data.message);
    return Ok();
 }
```

Comment: Web API uses Newtonsoft by default.  To use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`, the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` has to be configured manually.  MVC uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` by default.